# Create a smooth fade animation in android?

Tags: android

I'm attempting to fade between two background images on my Droid, but the animation seems to get 5fps if not less. Is there any method I can use other than fading in\out a couple image views that would be smoother?

Comment: Hmm.. what kind of device are you running it on? AlphaAnimations work fine on my Nexus One.

Comment: Droid, overclocked to 1ghz. These are 2 854x480 images faded simultaneously. I don't have this problem with smaller images. I think I need a hardware accelerated method.